# Why does PSQL complain about unknown relation: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "benannte_person" does not exist?

Tags: entity, psql, one-to-one, many-to-one, joincolumn

When I try to run a SpringBootTest using Testcontainers, I get a

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
...
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "benannte_person" does not exist
```

when I run a `findAll()` on the DAO and I don't know the reason, since in my whole code no '*benanntee_person*' can be found (not even in comments).

SQL DDL:

```
CREATE TYPE Erklaerungstyp AS ENUM ('aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd');
CREATE TYPE Geschlecht AS ENUM ('D', 'F', 'M');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Anschrift;
CREATE TABLE Anschrift (
  a_id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  Zusatz        VARCHAR(255),
  Strasse       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Hausnummer    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  plz           VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  Ort           VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  Bundesland    VARCHAR(20),
  Land          VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  create_Date   DATE NOT NULL,
  modify_Date   DATE
);
INSERT INTO Anschrift VALUES (1, null, 'Musterstrasse', '13M', '12345', 'Berlin', 'Berlin', 'Deutschland', '2001-09-28');
INSERT INTO Anschrift VALUES (2, 'bei Müller', 'Musterweg', '1-3', '54321', 'Musterhausen', 'Muster-Hausen', 'Deutschland', '2002-03-11');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ErklaerendePerson;
CREATE TABLE ErklaerendePerson (
  ep_id                 SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  Geschlecht            Geschlecht,
  Vorname               VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Familienname          VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Geburtsname           VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Titel                 VARCHAR(10),
  Geburtsdatum          Date NOT NULL,
  Geburtsort            VARCHAR(30),
  Anschrift             INTEGER REFERENCES Anschrift(a_id),
  Email                 VARCHAR(80),
  Telefon               VARCHAR(20),
  create_Date           DATE  NOT NULL,
  modify_Date           DATE
);
INSERT INTO ErklaerendePerson VALUES (1, 'M', 'Max', 'Mustermann', 'Mustermann', 'Dipl.-Inf.', '01.01.1901', 'Berlin', 1, 'Max.Mustermann@max.de',
'0111 12 34 56 789', '2001-09-28');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BenanntePerson;
CREATE TABLE BenanntePerson (
  bp_id         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  Geschlecht    Geschlecht,
  Vorname       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Familienname  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Geburtsdatum  Date NOT NULL,
  Geburtsort    VARCHAR(30),
  Anschrift     INTEGER REFERENCES Anschrift(a_id),
  Telefon       VARCHAR(20),
  Email         VARCHAR(80),
  create_Date   DATE NOT NULL,
  modify_Date   DATE
);
INSERT INTO BenanntePerson VALUES (1, 'F', 'Maxine', 'Musterpaar', '12.07.1971', 'Berlin', 1, '0111 444 55 66', 'Maxine.Musterpaar@xxx.de', '2001-09-28');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Erklaerung;
CREATE TABLE Erklaerung (
  ose_id            SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ep_id             INTEGER REFERENCES ErklaerendePerson(ep_id),
  bp_id             INTEGER REFERENCES BenanntePerson(bp_id),
  Anmerkung         VARCHAR(120),
  Erklaerungstyp    Erklaerungstyp NOT NULL,
  create_Date       DATE NOT NULL,
  modify_Date       DATE
);
INSERT INTO Erklaerung VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'blablabla', 'VOLLUMFASSEND', '2020.02.20');
COMMIT;
```

Entity `BenanntePerson`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BenanntePerson")
@Data
public class BenanntePerson implements Serializable {
    @Id
//    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "bp_id")
    private Integer bpId;

    @Column(name = "Vorname", nullable = true)
    private String vorname;

    @Column(name = "Familienname", nullable = true)
    private String familienname;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "Geburtsdatum", nullable = false)
    private Date geburtsdatum;

    @Column(name = "Geburtsort", nullable = false)
    private String geburtsort;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", nullable = false)
    private Anschrift anschrift;

    @Column(name = "Email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "Telefonnummer", nullable = false)
    private String telefonnummer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "benanntePerson")
    private Set<Erklaerung> erklaerungen;

    @Column(name = "create_Date", insertable = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Timestamp createDate;

    @Column(name = "modify_Date", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp modifyDate;
}
```

The `Erklaerung` entity for the relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Erklaerung")
@Data
public class Erklaerung implements Serializable {
    @Id
    //    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ose_id")
    private Integer oseId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ep_id", nullable = false)
    private ErklaerendePerson erklaerendePerson;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bp_id", nullable = false)
    private BenanntePerson benanntePerson;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "Erklaerungstyp", nullable = false)
    private Erklaerungstyp erklaerungstyp;

    @Column(name = "Anmerkung", nullable = true)
    private String anmerkung;

    @Column(name = "create_Date", insertable = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Timestamp createDate;

    @Column(name = "modify_Date", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp modifyDate;
}
```

The corresponding JPA DAO:

```
@Repository
public interface BenanntePersonJpaDao extends JpaRepository<BenanntePerson, Integer> {
    @NotNull
    List<BenanntePerson> findByFamilienname(@NotNull String familienname);
    @NotNull
    List<BenanntePerson> findByVorname(@NotNull String vorname);
}
```

Why does PSQL complain??

Answer (score 0):

It's simply because `@JoinColumn(name = "a_id", nullable = false)` doesn't match with the database table because there is no 'a_id' column. It is called 'Anschrift' in the table definition. Hence, renaming '`Anschrift`' to '`a_id`' in the table definition solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while but I was stucked in the very same problem and found the solution :
You miss the pg option `stringtype=unspecified`. This btw should currently be used when running without test container, seek it in `spring.datasource.url` property.

At some point in your config you should currently be using `PostgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl()`. You should replace it with `PostgreSQLContainer.constructUrlForConnection("?stringtype=unspecified")`.